How to protect against fake gold bars?
Most Minted Gold such as PAMP comes with QR code for authentication. You simply scan the QR code at the back of the packet and it gives you the certificate in the app. My question is what's stopping the fakes to replicate the QR code along with the fake gold. Does that mean there is no way the gold bars from PAMP, Perth mint or Credit Suisse can be certified by using QR code or serial number, which can be replicated as well?

If you buy gold bullion directly from Credit Suisse, or better yet, from a national mint, e.g. the U.S. Mint in America, you need not worry about fakes. Also, you will be charged a minimum or no commission. Why would anyone ever by gold bars from a disreputable source, or one that has a QR code for verification?! A QR code isn't a form of authentication.

@EllieK, yes sure, but buying from the mints directly imply one has to pay the premium, buying from the open market (individuals who just wanna sell their bullion) means that one pay only the gold price at its face value and thats how gold shops make money.

Comments have been cleaned up - please remember they are only for clarifying or improving the question, not answering it or any side discussions.

I don't know anything about this particular QR code system, or the app you mention, but I can work some things out from first principles.
To answer the question, "whats stopping the fakes to replicate the QR code along with the fake gold" -- nothing really. QR codes are absolutely trivial to copy. You can do it with a photocopier, or a camera and a printer. Much easier to copy than gold bars.
However, the packet might be difficult to copy (provided you know what the packet is supposed to look like, and can spot a fake or tampered packet). If so, then the QR code might provide some confidence that what you're holding is what the producer assayed, because it lets you check with the producer what they assayed and put out.
The QR code may also be a convenient way to look up the serial number on the bar. Instead of copying the serial number and calling law enforcement (or Credit Suisse) to ask if that bar has been reported stolen or re-melted, you can just scan the QR code in a handy app and then (I'm guessing) double-check that the serial number on the bar corresponds with the serial number in the app. Saves a bit of typing, which is exactly what QR codes were invented to do.
From a comment, "I have seen people saying just scan the QR code to justify the item is not fake if it leads to an authentic certificate" -- definitely incorrect.
It is not enough to "just scan the QR code" for the reason you have identified: if that's all you do then nothing has connected the QR code to the item claiming to be a gold bar.
Surely, whoever wrote that would not believe me if I handed them a piece of paper with a photocopy of the legit QR code on it, and told them it was gold? It's paper! It doesn't even weigh an ounce (or whatever it's supposed to)! You would know that it's not gold without scanning the QR code, and scanning the code changes nothing. But they said, "just scan the QR code, and if it leads to an authentic certificate then it must be gold". Rubbish.
Neither should they believe me if it wasn't a piece of paper, but an obviously-tampered packet. I could have taken the gold out and replaced it with something else.
Neither (and this is the subtle bit) should they believe me if it all looks plausible, but they don't know how to tell for sure and they don't know what the QR code or the packet are supposed to look like. Anybody can create a QR code and a web page for it to point to.
Hopefully the app is checking that it's the right website and so on. Perhaps (like the serial number), someone whose gold is stolen can report it stolen, and the app will flag that QR code for you so that you know not to buy it. Perhaps the app is doing something when it scans the QR code, to at least also make sure it's the correct colour and on the correct kind of material, that it's not just a photocopy. I don't know.
I do know that if someone down the pub tells you to scan a QR code, to go to a website in your browser, then it doesn't prove anything unless you can check the authenticity of the web page. And even if the certificate checks out, it proves nothing about whatever they've glued the QR code to.
To answer the question, "How to protect against fake gold bars?" -- this is a complex subject. I don't know the details, but I know that producers, dealers, and law enforcement have a number of systems going on, some old and some new. None of them is perfect, and particularly none of them is perfect if you're just a retail buyer who doesn't know how any of them is supposed to work. Somebody who tells you this is easy for you to do yourself is either wrong or lying to you. Some random seller who tells you that you can authenticate what they're selling you just by following the instructions they give you, is lying. You need to first find a trustworthy source (such as Credit Suisse, hopefully), and then follow their instructions.
The point of certificates of authenticity is that if everything works out, and Credit Suisse has given you a way to confirm that what the retailer is selling you is what Credit Suisse produced (and isn't known to be stolen), then you don't have to trust the retailer to tell you what you're buying. Credit Suisse tells you what you're buying. But it's still quite a big "if", with some work to do. If you want to be sure you're buying gold, learn to assay gold. But you'll have to take it out of the packet to do that. If you're happy to buy Credit-Suisse-backed QR codes, just scan the code and ignore the alleged gold ;-) Somewhere in between, I expect those who follow the proper instructions can get some benefit from this QR code, so that the gold stays in the packet but they're reasonably confident it's real.

'But they said, "just scan the QR code, and if it leads to an authentic certificate then it must be gold". Rubbish' Maybe it's an NFT. The real gold was destroyed and converted to a digital form. I mean, you can sell a banana for millions of dollars and not even deliver a banana these days.

@JimmyJames I know this was just a joke, but a QR code can't contain an NFT any more than it can contain a gold bar. A QR code is just a way of writing some text; it doesn't provide anything that text doesn't, other than being easy for a computer to read. An NFT, meanwhile, is an item in a list, labelled with who currently owns it; the "clever" bit is that the list is de-centralized (the "blockchain"), and the owner has a way to securely prove who they are (using a cryptographic signature).

Remember Archimedes "Eureca!"?
Density of bar can be determined by comparing its weight to its volume. Density of gold is known, and not easy to replicate.
If you are seriously concerned, an NMR assay might be possible without breaking the seal. That may not be worth the cost for small quantities.
Of course, that's assuming that you are allowed to handle the gold long enough to test it.
But if you don't trust the seller, frankly, why are you even considering the transaction? If it's because they are cheaper than everyone else, there may be a good reason for that and it may not be the one of they claim. If they aren't, go to someone you do trust.

And if you do trust the seller, how does the QR code add anything further? It might be that this whole QR code system is spurious.

Tungsten is denser than gold and about 0.1% of the cost.

@user71659 - It also does not alloy well with gold and is much harder, so even if you could dilute gold with tungsten, you would not be able to add much before it was clearly too hard to be pure gold. You would have to put the gold around the tungsten, which would be easily discovered if someone tried to cut one of your bars in half or melted it.

It's also half as electrically conductive, but since the surface layer of gold would conduct electricity, I am not sure how easily that could be used. You could also try certain acids, but, well, you probably want to keep your gold....

This is getting out of the realm of money and into materials science. I can think of some ways of trying to detect tungsten inclusions, but I can't say whether they would work. Of course, at some point the cost of testing starts to become a significant percentage of the value of the gold, at which point we come back to whether you really want to buy gold or not, whether you can find a source you are more comfortable with, and why you need physical gold in the first place.

@keshlam I think it’s not the method but the possibility itself of non-destructive composition testing that matters. Technically it is as simple as taking an NMR spectrum, which tells you the exact composition, detecting every single element and their ratio with a sensitivity much below a percent. This is quite standard nowadays in any material laboratory.

@Neinstein: That makes perfect sense; I should have thought of NMR/MRI. In fact, that would be worth turning into an answer, since it is a near-ultimate response to the question. (Only near because it still requires that you trust the machine and its operators, and the cost may be excessive unless you are testing a tray full of bars simultaneously.). If you'd rather not, I can edit it into mine.

@Obie2.0 Fraudsters are already ahead of that. If you do a solid W core, you can discover that by ultrasound. So you salt it; add fine dust. In all, density is a poor measure because it can be easily fooled.

@user71659 - "Fraudsters are already ahead of that." Do you have a citation? I have heard of gold bars with tungsten cores, but if there is an example of there being a gold bar adulterated with "fine tungsten dust," I haven't heard of it. I imagine that would be detectable with an optical microscrope, or maybe just with the eye, depending on the quantity of dust.

And NMR should show the difference, as previously observed. I have no idea whether there is any way to cheat that. I come back to "if you don't trust the vendor, buy elsewhere, or buy something else."

@user71659 yes I also agree that density can be fooled as I have seen some video where the mass and volume are the same and there is a gold foil with tungsten inner core. It will fool XRF machine and scratch tests.

@keshlam Feel free to edit your answer. Though I still feel that the method itself is not that important, only the existence of such methods itself.

@Obie2.0 "which would be easily discovered if someone tried to cut one of your bars in half or melted it" I find it unlikely that an individual would cut open (or melt) a gold bar they have purchased. It would make it much harder to sell or exchange later and effectively reduce its value. And for that same reason, no seller (legitimate or not) is going to allow you to do this prior to purchase. They will be long gone before you figure out the scam.

@JimmyJames - I saw an image online of a gold-coated tungsten bar that someone had discovered by cutting it in half. I assume it was one that they had been sold, not that they cut it before purchase.

And I know of another case where a tungsten bar was discovered by melting.

@Obie2.0 I can imagine someone who thinks they might have been ripped off doing that, but you aren't seriously suggesting that this is a common practice, are you?  If you cut into a bar and its solid gold, you now need to have it re-assayed. If you cut into it and find it's not solid gold, you have an expensive paperweight (well, 2, perhaps.) Not much upside, especially if the seller has ghosted.

Of course, if you made the mistake of buying an un-assayed bar, or bought it from somebody who would have falsified/not checked the assay before selling it to you and who isn't willing to guarantee that it is what it says it is... Here as always, buyer beware.

Fake gold bars are not much common these days. Here's why:
One of the most obvious distinct properties of gold is its density - 19g/cm3. For comparison: copper is 8.9, iron is 7.6, lead and silver are ~11 (all these out of memory), water for comparison is 1.0, air is 0.0012.
Few substances are denser than gold and most of them are way too expensive for a gold substitute.
Density is easy to measure with very good accuracy using tools of 2-digit price range and an hour of learning.
One cannot dilute or substitute gold with lighter metals without being quickly caught.
In order to fake gold by density, there are few options available. If we skip those that are radioactive and/or more expensive than gold, we are left with tungsten.
Tungsten has density that is very, very close to gold. On the other hand, it has other properties that are profoundly different:

Melting temperatures differ by more than 1000C and the two metals don't mix so we have to create a fake by using a tungsten bar and enveloping it with gold.
Speed of sound. While not obvious, the difference in the speed of sound will make a gold bar with a tungsten inlet emit different sound when carefully suspended and hit. Simple electronic devices that measure the physical dimensions of a bar by ultrasound will show numbers inconsistent with a ruler or a caliper.
Electrical ressitance. While I am not aware of any easy to use tools for measuring the very low resistances related to gold, this, too, can be used to distinguish a faked bar.
Visual appearance. If the tungsten fake is not completely covered with gold, one will see a colorless, silvery metal with much less luster.
X-ray extinction - while 10 years ago this may not have been an important factor, these days the relevant gear is cheap and available.

In short, way too much knowledge and technology these days in way too many hands makes faking gold a bad business.

Selling bad fakes to rubes might still be an adequate business, though. Don't buy gold from a bloke down the pub who's giving you a great deal.

If you're selling bad fakes to rubes, go Maltese Falcon, just sell them lead and split. Or just take the money and deliver nothing; see the scam tag.

@keshlam in a social environment where one can deliver nothing or an obvious fake and get away with this at least short term, the problem is not limited or related to gold.

Yes I have seen replication of weight and density of gold coin using thick gold outer foil (which will pass scratch test) and tungsten inner core. But again the bar must be removed from the package to conduct several tests which nullifies the assay info on the package

@gfdsal The MRI test would not require breaking the seal, I think.

@fraxinus: Then Know Your Seller and make sure they stand behind the product. Or buy a product that is less vulnerable to this, such as a gold based mutual fund (I assume that exists). If you are a survivalist, remember that unless the crisis passes quickly gold's value is going to fall off a cliff compared to things people will actually need.

"Fake gold bars are not much common these days" - you clearly don't follow what goes on in China https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=china+observer+fake+gold

You can always test the bar, the weight/volume ratio is pretty easy to confirm. You can then proceed to cut them to pieces or melt to confirm uniformity.
Certificates of authenticity are only worth the paper they're printed on if you trust the issuer. It seems that you don't.

I know the gold can be certainly verified by distructive tests, but my question is can QR code scans be faked so that scanning leads to authentic certificate from say PAMP? This will tell that one can trust the certificate of authenticity or not.

I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking if someone can copy an image and print it again somewhere else? What does "can QR code scans be faked" mean? You should probably talk to those who provide the certificates how they guard against potential fraudulent copies, but it is most definitely possible.

Yes, that was my concern. So having a same QR code printed on the assay of the fake bar of same weightage would lead to authentic certificate making person with fake gold bar believing that he has authentic bar. I am asking this because I have seen people saying just scan the QR code to justify the item is not fake if it leads to an authentic certificate.

It will/may depend on what the QR codes encode/link to. No idea how they work, but if, for example, they say little else than "this is a gold bar", they're probably not worth the paper they're printed on. If they were to securely encode the weight/size to very high precision, that might make it harder for a scammer to fake (but might not).

I've never bought these products and I know nothing about the QR codes, but working from first principles: obviously QR codes can be photocopied. Obviously you could open the packet, replace the gold with lead, and sell a packet of spray-painted lead with a QR code on the packet. But could you seal it up again properly? Putting a QR code on the packet might help if we believe that the packet can't be tampered with, and that only Credit Suisse can make the packets, and we trust Credit Suisse to assay the gold for us (but maybe don't 100% trust the retailer).

Finally, never mind copying them: anyone can make their own QR codes. So you'd need to check the domain in the URL that the QR code takes you to, before believing that the pictures really are of the certified item. Any crook who can make a fake bar of gold, can make (or hire someone to make) a fake web page, and make a QR code pointing to that page. Maybe the idea is that dealers will already know from experience what the packets are supposed to be like: having assessed that, the QR code is an extra check and (like the serial number) allows stolen items to be flagged?

@gfdsal copying a QR code takes as much as a scanner. Is that what you mean? Or are you interested in whether there’s something specific safety measurement in the data encoded in the QR code that makes it sure that the code applies to only that specific gold bar? If the latter, perhaps it would help to clarify that in the question itself. (I’m not sure why the former possibility would be doubted.)

@Neinstein Technically looking at the answers, QR code is pointless when it comes to authentication of the item in the packet as QR code can be replicated from a known gold bar of same weight. Also the data encoded in QR code does point to specific gold bar say 1 ounce, but scammers can use this QR code and make fake gold bar of 1 ounce so the authentication method using QR code is pointless.

QR codes are widely used by scammers in phishing emails because they know that some people will trust the codes more than a simple link, even though there's no actual difference.

@barbecue: While that's one reason for it, part of it is that QR codes tend to bypass a bunch of defenses.  See this post and this one.

This is seriously one of the most confused pages on this site!  (1) Pamp's absurd "surface fingerprint" thing IS RIDICULOUS, it is an industry joke, it's a meaningless gimmick.  (2) Pamp's absurd bars have a plastic packet (only an IDIOT would buy any form of gold in a plastic packet) and on the backl theyr write the serial number rof the (rofl) "surface fingerprint" and there's a qr code to save you typing that serial number.  The serial number and the qr code have utterly, utterly, utterly, utterly nothing to do with "guaranteeing!" the bar.

I am publishing a second answer because it deals with profoundly different aspect of the problem. After being a chemist, I am also an IT person.
This is how QR authenticity control works (pretty much not only for the gold bars)
As already dealt with in another answers, the QR code can confirm the connection between the certificate and the issuer (i.e. the mint) and this is an important improvement over the paper certificate. Thus, the fake vendor is limited to only using copies of an authentic certificates.
On the other hand, it can do nothing to confirm the connection between the certificate and the piece of metal it is supposed to relate to.
On the third hand, the particular customer is not the only one to check its QR-backed certificate and a lot of consequences emerge thereof.
When one scans a QR code and opens the website it points to, the website content is transferred to their device, bit a great deal of information flows backwards - e.g. the IP address (along with its geo-ip location data), a relation to the previous website visits, maybe some connection to social network accounts and so on, depending on a lot of factors.
All this data gets logged in some database and can be data mined and cross-checked against other databases, e.g. the mint production records, the distribution network records, various financial institution records and, in some cases, the social networks and the law enforcement databases.
Generally, all this data may allow quickly tracing the abused copies of certificates down to a single point of leak - be it a customer, a point of sale, a retail operation or something else.
This is how the hypothetical reputable mint (with the generous help of its own customers, the modern technology and the law enforcement institutions) can weed the fake vendors out.
... and my example is by no means exhaustive.

So technically you are saying its always a good thing to scan QR code of the bullion that you buy to have your device login record with the Mint for additional security? its like registering the purchase of the bullion directly from the mint?

@gfdsal No, he said this: The QR code can do nothing to confirm the connection between the certificate and the piece of metal it is supposed to relate to.

@gfdsal For God's sake.  Let's go back to step one.  YOU NEVER, EVER, EVER, EVER BUY GOLD BULLION THAT IS IN A PLASTIC PACKET. THOSE ARE PURELY NOVELTY ITEMS SOLD TO IDIOTS. if you take a small bar that's in a "sealed plastic!" in to a gold dealer they will (A) call the cops if they get the sense you might be a scammer (B) Laugh at you if you're someone who knows better and you're trying one on, or (C) if you're a "grannie" who got sold a "gold! bar! - in! plastic!" by some phone scammers, they will break off and throw away the plastic, decide if they wanna buy it / if it seems real, and

pay you.  So if you see gold IN A PLASTIC THING, WALK THE HELL AWAY.  Further, Pamp is trying their utterly silly "fingerprint!" thing, which is laughable and stupid. nobody cares abotu it and it is totally ignored by actual dealers.

I'm afraid this answer is not so much nonsense, but just completely misguided and has nothing to do with anything. sorry.

@Fattie I myself did some data digging, ad hoc in a related situation and without prior preparation (a lot of useful data was not logged). Later, some people were sent to a correctional institution. And I am not a forensic expert at any rate.

@gfdsal maybe. The website may or may not do the proper things.

@EllieK the answer pretty much does not assume anything in regard to the mint, except maybe some common sense on their part.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Fattie, this makes sense. I thought the plastic assay package adds value to the underlying product, which puts fear to many people of opening one because it might devalue the gold, which I believe is a motivation for the scammers as they know people would be reluctant to open the sealed 'assayed package' leading to its devaluation and hence easily trade fakes to untrained individuals. We live in a world where we cant event trust pagers from an authentic source ;)

The QR code identifies the purported batch, but authenticity is apparently verified by "fingerprinting" the surface
https://www.pamp.com/veriscan/ claims that it uses

microscopic ‘surface profiles’ as individual and distinctive as a fingerprint

to verify the identity of the bar, so the QR code says "I am from batch XYZ" [1], and then the surface of each bar in batch XYZ can be compared to the bar being scanned, so you can confirm that this bar is one of those minted in that batch.
In short: the QR code doesn't validate anything itself.
[1]: the FAQ has a question "Why do I get a ‘PASS’ result when I scan two different bars that have the same serial number?", so the QR codes are not unique to individual bars.

The pamp system is utterly useless and farcical in the industry.  not that anyone would bother for a novelty bar but if someone wanted to tungsten a stupid "surface! profile!" bar they'd do that, just cutting it carefully and dressing the sides

this is a good insight! I was hoping that there is something unique about the bar that links it to QR code, although all 1 ounce fortuna pamp gold bullion looks the same, you are saying that veriscan (which uses smart phone for fingerprinting) looks for markings of the batch or something unique in that batch which scammers may not know..?

Also +1 for the specific FAQ, I am surprised that the answer to that question of "Why do I get a ‘PASS’ result when I scan two different bars that have the same serial number?" doesnt even makes sense. The FAQ asks about same serial number, but the answer is about same batch (rather then same serial number!)

hi @gfdsal yes as I explain in comments, you have been utterly misinformed and are offbase conceptually about the pamp's novelty "fingerprint!" system


Most Minted Gold such as PAMP comes with QR code for authentication

That statement is staggeringly, astoundingly, astonishingly incorrect.

The rest of the question on this page appears to be about the "telephone" or "novelty bullion" market.
(You know those radio ads "Because of RETIREMENT and FEDS then YOU need GOLD" - and they sell 40, 50 dollar gold "bars" lol to grannies via phone marketing.)
Such "telephone" or "novelty bullion" pieces are sold in hard plastic cases (gold in any sort of plastic or covering at all is the instant mark that this is just "novelty bullion" - obviously never ever touch it or have anything to do with it).
Further, Pamp and others have been trying on a bizarre "fingerprinting!" gimmick in the "telephone" or "novelty bullion" market. There happens to be a serial number on the back. None of this has anything at all to do with the question "how do dealers check if gold bars are real and not tungsten core"?
if you want to know "how do dealers check if gold bars are real and not tungsten core" simply google that.
(Note that very simply YES occasionally a dealer gets caught-out, someone slips through either a tungsten kilobar or even a tungsten normal bar (so called "400 oz bar").  It never happened to me once, but it can happen. This is no astonishingly different than that, occasionally, fine art dealers, say, will buy a fake. No amazing mystery.)

The novelty bullion market! Yes, I know it well. I used to live in NYC, recall that on 42nd St in Manhattan, tacky merchants sell 1 gram gold "ingots" in clear plastic, usually for twice or three times the price of 1/28 ounce of gold, and they probably aren't even gold.

I am confused.  Presumably, you would define something like this (https://www.costco.com/1-oz-gold-bar-pamp-suisse-lady-fortuna-veriscan-new-in-assay.product.4000186760.html) as "novelty bullion".  It is from PAMP and sold in plastic.  But it is still an ounce of gold.  It is sold for the spot price of gold plus a very small markup.  It is sold by a reputable vendor and made by a reputable mint.  If you happen to be someone that wants to own a small amount of physical gold, that seems like an eminently reasonable way to purchase it.

It's problematic if someone cold calls you trying to sell you gold (or just about anything else) over the phone because it's inevitably going to be overpriced.  It's problematic if you're buying good sold from the trunk of some guy's car.  But that's true no matter what you're buying.

@EllieK right, indeed

@JustinCave Costco gold lol. yeah that would be "insane".  if you want an ounce of gold .......... buy an ounce of gold.  Any totally normal 1 oz gold coin.  It is instantly and immediately available from normal gold sources 24/7.

"If you happen to be someone that wants to own a small amount of physical gold, that seems like an eminently reasonable way to purchase it". An ounce of gold is not "small" it is a real one ounce gold bullion round.  "If you happen to be someone that wants to own a small amount of physical gold" .. if so, it is utterly astounding that you wouldn't ....................... purchase a normal completely world-standard 1 oz gold round, at a cheaper price, instead of some insane novelty item from Costco (WTF?).  It's somewhat hard to dump novelty items like that when you want to.

{@JustinCave A real world example is, I was on a run at a dealer in Geneve, so I had a [large count of] normal 1 oz rounds, a few kilobars and so on.  As well as the pile of 1 oz rounds, I had, literally exactly, 2x "granny gold" or "telemarketing gold" supposed/whatever "gold in plastic, with a stamp on the gold of a goddess or something" So there were 2x "granny gold" or "telemarketing gold" 1oz items (I'm pretty sure one was literally pamp, I have no idea the other, there are various outfits in different regions that produce this junk). Stef. just grumbled, smashed them out of the idiotic

.. plastic, gave them a bite, and gave me spot for them as a courtesy - of course they both went straight in to melt, nobody wants that nonsense, it's not "bullion". Anyone else he would have just said "Sorry, we don't buy this, try uhh The Gap or something down the street, maybe they'll take it, bye." Bullion is bullion.  Even the Perth mint now does shit like colorized dragons and stuff - why?  Just stick to the most standard ordinary 1oz rounds (Or, better, just get kilobars.)

@Fattie - I'm still confused.  Costco in this example is selling an ounce of gold.  It is selling that ounce of gold at the spot price of gold plus a small markup similar to any other precious metal dealer.  The $0.001 worth of plastic packaging may not add any value for you but it hardly detracts from the value (and putting it in plastic at a minimum protects you from someone shaving off small amounts from the gold you're buying).  A dealer might take a second to pop it out of the plastic to test it before buying it but dealers are constantly buying gold in the form of rings, chains, etc.

@JustinCave right, (a) you know how you can (just as you say, extremely easily) sell gold rings etc, you get much less than spot for that (b) dealers just don't like 1 oz bullion that is not just "one of the usual normal vanilla one ounce coins" {as a simple real world example, say we were mates IRL and you wanted to sell that costo-pamp item and you also had just a normal maple, kriugerrand or such and you wanted some cash and you asked me if I'd give you spot cash for them, I'd take the maple straight away but i wouldn't bother with the pamp-thing. why would I want the hassle? notice my "A

real world example is," anecdote just above. why would I take on a (let's call it) "granny/telemarketing -type" item when I (or anyone) can instantly buy ordinary universally traded maples (from another guy at the bar) at spot.  that being said (C) yes, you're quite right, your Specific example of the costco-pamp item is, let's say the "least possible example of a granny/telemarketing -type bullion item" if that makes sense!  Anyway!  Rock on.  I think the main point of my answer/comments on this page is that the question asked is totally malformed. (a) the serial number thing is utterly

irrelevant and has nothing to do with "authentication",(b) the term "authentication" has utterly nothing, at all, to do with a fungible substance like oil or timber or an atom such as AU (the OP may be thinking of collectible items like baseball cards???) (c) bullion doesn't come in plastic, the OP is looking at a "telemarketing type" thing (d) Pamp's totally absurd fingerprinting! gimmick is risible abnd laughed at in the business (nobody buying metal would use that as part of checking it is real solid bullion; indeed if I was a tungsten baker as mentioned above I WOULD USE those as the

start of a process of making a tungsten bar!!  As you might be able to sell it to am amateur or something) (e) if OP was wondering "how do gold dealers check if a bar is not a tungsten bar", just google and finally (F) the OP envisages a world where you buy/sell gold "to someone at a bar", you don't do that, it's nonsensical (you can buy/sell to, you know, "Canada" at any moment); and if you did there is nothing more than "using your judgement" that it isn't a tungsten round, no mystyery!  PHEW!  cheers
